# Обновление в PUT запросе

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

Есть две сущности:

Book

```
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
@Getter
@Setter
public class BookEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "vendor")
    private String vendor;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "genreBookId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<GenreEntity> genres;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="library_id")
    private Library libraryId;

    public BookEntity() {
    }
```

и Genre

```
@Entity
@Table(name="genre")
@Getter
@Setter
public class GenreEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id")
    private BookEntity genreBookId;

    public GenreEntity() {
    }
}
```

Сервис

```
@Override
    public BookEntity updateBook(Long bookId, BookEntity updateBook) throws BookNotFoundException {
        return bookRepository.findById(bookId)
                .map(book -> {
                    book.setVendor(updateBook.getVendor());
                    book.setTitle(updateBook.getTitle());
                    book.setDescription(updateBook.getDescription());
                    
                    updateBook.getGenres().forEach(g -> g.setGenreBookId(book));
                    book.setGenres(updateBook.getGenres());

                    return bookRepository.save(book);
                })
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException("Книга с таким идентификатором не найдена")); //исправить
    }
```

Запросы выполняю через Postman.

Отправляя такой put запрос

```
{
    "vendor": "7613252153-32",
    "title": "Название",
    "description": "Описание",
    "genres": [
        {
            "title": "Другой жанр"
        },
        {
            "title": "Другой жанр2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Ещё один жанр"
        }
    ],
    "libraryId": 1
}
```

в столбце genres данные не обновляются, а добавляются, т.е. к двум предыдущим добавляются ещё 3 жанра

```
"genres": [
        {
            "title": "Старый жанр"
        },
        {
            "title": "Старый жанр2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Другой жанр"
        },
        {
            "title": "Другой жанр2"
        },
        {
            "title": "Ещё один жанр"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Чтобы "обновлять" жанры, вам следует передавать их соответствующие идентификаторы, однако скорей всего это будет неправильно, так как в результате такого апдейта могут "обновиться" жанры для нескольких связанных книг.

Comment: `book.getGenres().clear(); book.getGenres().addAll(updateBook.getGenres());`  Это не обновит жанры, а удалить существующие у книги и создаст пришедшие в метод, с новыми Id. Если нет других сущностей, у которых есть ссылка на жанр с вешним ключем, то такая реализация может быть.

Comment: book.getGenres().clear(); не удаляет

Comment: Добавьте в аннотацию `orphanRemoval = true` чтоб получилось `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "genreBookId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)`

Comment: @MrFylypenko , спасибо! Всё получилось!